# CLT for product of random variables with RHS dependent on $n$

Tags: probability-theory

I don't know how to deal with the following question:

We have iid RV $(X_n)$ with $P(X_i = a) = p$ and $P(X_i = \frac{1}{a}) = 1-p$, where $a > 1$ and we look at $Y_n := \prod_{i=1}^n X_i$.
We are supposed to the determine all $p$ s.t. $P(Y_n \geq 1)$ goes to $0$ as $n\to \infty$ using the CLT.

Here is what I got

$$\mu := E\log X_i = (2p-1)\log a$$
$$\sigma^2:=\operatorname{Var}\log X_i = 4p(1-p)(\log a)^2$$

Now

$$P(Y_n \geq 1) = P(\sum_{i=1}^n \log X_i \geq 0) = P(\frac{1}{\sqrt n \sigma}(\sum_{i=1}^n \log X_i - n\mu) \geq -\sqrt n \frac\mu\sigma)$$

but the RHS depends on $n$, so I can't apply the CLT for $n\to \infty$. What can I do?

Comment: $\sigma^2 < 0$?

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 Yeah. Sorry, I meant $a > 1$ btw.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, but that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 I kept making the same sign error. I think now it's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually still apply the CLT. In $P(\frac{1}{\sqrt n \sigma}(\sum_{i=1}^n \log X_i - n\mu) \geq -\sqrt n \frac\mu\sigma)$ the RHS of the inequality tends to $\infty$ or $-\infty$ depending on the sign of $\mu/\sigma$ (which you can compute as a function of $p$). The probability a standard normal covariate, the limit of the LHS, exceeds $\infty$ is 0 and exceeds $-\infty$ is 1. More formally, let $M>0$ be given and suppose the sign of $\mu/\sigma$ is negative. Then for all $n>M^2$,

$$
P(\frac{1}{\sqrt n \sigma}(\sum_{i=1}^n \log X_i - n\mu) \geq -\sqrt n \frac\mu\sigma)\le P(\frac{1}{\sqrt n \sigma}(\sum_{i=1}^n \log X_i - n\mu) \geq -M \frac\mu\sigma)\leadsto P(G\ge -M \frac\mu\sigma)
$$
where $G$ is standard normal. Since this holds for all $M>0$, the probability must in fact be $0$. You can do the case of the other sign similarly.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful.